# Objective-C: How to send a post request with a multidimensional array of type key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, http, afnetworking

From application, written in Objective (we use AFNetworking), I need to send a POST request, in the body of which - a multidimensional array of the type "key": "value"

We send request this way:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
                    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
                    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@“application/json” forHTTPHeaderField:@“Accept”];
                    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@“multipart/form-data” forHTTPHeaderField:@“Content-Type”];


                   [manager POST:url parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {


                       for (UIImage* image in photoArray) {

                           NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);


                            [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataImage name:randomString fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@.jpeg”,randomString] mimeType:@“image/jpeg”];
                        }


                   } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {



                   } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

                       NSLog(@“!!!!! %@“, responseObject);

                       if (success) {

                           [KVNProgress dismiss];
                            success(responseObject);

                       }


                   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                       NSLog(@“%@“, error.localizedFailureReason);
                        [KVNProgress showError];

                   }];
```

And this way we form NSDictionary:

```
NSString*name = model.name;
NSString*lat = model.lat;
NSString*lon = model.lon;
NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"name",lat,@"lat",lon,@"lon", nil];
[addressArray addObject:dic];
```

Here's what we get on Objective
[image: 1]

Here is what request the server receives
[image: 2]
And here's what should come
[image: 3]

How to build an object on Objective so that data [address] came to the HTTP server as indicated in the 3 picture?

Comment: Copy/paste code/data, not screenshot. It's harder to read, links can die, and if we want to be quick/import your code in a test app, we'd have to write them all by hand and miss a potential error on your side.

Comment: @Larme, thank you for advice
I'll add it in few minutes, got troubles with ide

Comment: Type `"key":"value"` sounds like a dictionary, not an array. What is the form of the server data you are showing? That doesn't look like JSON, or any other syntax I've seen before.

Comment: @DuncanC yes, it's dictionary. I'm showing on 2-d and 3-d picture just body of request which  came to server.

Comment: @Larme, all done

Comment: Seeing `data[address]` as a key seems quite strange.